# Mysqli_set_charset() отказывается работать

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Никак не могу врубиться, почему функция отказывается работать.

```
$db->set_charset("utf-8");
```

Возвращает false почему-то. Соединение с базой открыто, данные извлекаются и всё такое. Однако кодировка меняться отказывается. Пробовал ради эксперимента менять на какой-нибудь windows-1251 - тоже не работает.

Куда копать?

Comment: @Garfild, $db - это что вообще за объект, каким классом объявлен?

Comment: $db = new mysqli(...);

Comment: @Garfild, а если дефис убрать в UTF-8?

Comment: Жесть. У меня разрыв шаблона)) оно работает))))
Странно, что мне такая мысль в голову не пришла. Хотя я скорее всего её отклонил с мыслью "не, бред".
Почему везде юзается с дефисом, а тут без?

Comment: @Garfild, я тоже сначала прикинул, что вообще-то верно писать с дефисом. Скорее всего, просто MySQL воспринимает его как минус, поэтому все дефисы в кодировках убиты (ссылка на их список есть на странице доки по `set_charset()`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

После `mysql_connect(....);` напиши `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");`

Comment: 1. Пробовал - тоже отказывается.  
2. This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended. (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: Вы используете mysqli. Но об этом не указали.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел рабочий  и корректный вариант:

```
    /* change character set to utf8 */

if (!mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8")) {

    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

else {

printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($mysqli));

}
```

Правда, он в процедурном стиле, а не в ООП.